# How to create a nested list of variable depth with indexed elements

Tags: list-manipulation, iteration, indexed-variable, indexing

i want to obtain this definition of a nested list

```
t = Table[C[i, j], {i, 3}, {j, 3}]
```

with arbitrary depth,

```
t = Table[C[i, j ... p,q], {i, 3}, {j, 3} ... {p, 3}, {q, 3}]
```

I have tried `Nest` like so,

```
Nest[Table[#1, {t, 3}] &, C, 2]
```

but do not manage to get the indices into the element as in C[i, j, ...].

Comment: You could use `Outer[C, Range[4], Range[5], Range[3]]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try [`Array`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Array.html):

```
Array[c, {3, 3, 3, 3}]
```

[image]

```
arraydepth = 3;
Array[c, ConstantArray[3, arraydepth]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate on b.gates.you.know.what's comment, this is a scalable version equivalent to kglr's solution:

```
Outer[c, Sequence @@ ConstantArray[{1, 2, 3}, 4]] === Array[c, {3, 3, 3, 3}]
```

> True

`{1, 2, 3}` can be a list of any elements.